# Where relative file names begin on android

Tags: android

I am trying to build an android application that lets me view a collection of PDF documents that are stored within the app. Other stack posts have lead me to the solution below. However, I am confused about what file paths I should use. Should I base the file paths on the "app" folder or the "project" folder? Or should I be using the file path of where it would be stored on the mobile device?

```
    File codeOfPoints = new File("/pdf/CoP_Full.pdf");
    String path = getFilesDir() + codeOfPoints.getAbsolutePath();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
            Uri.parse(path));

    intent.setType("application/pdf");
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
    if (activities.size() > 0) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

The above file structure would be based on the app folder.

Comment: "that are stored within the app" -- you need to be much more specific about what this means. Where, exactly, are these PDFs? In `src/main/assets/` of your `app` module? In `src/main/res/raw/` of your `app` module? Somewhere else?

Comment: In the snippet above, they are within /pdf/CoP_Full.pdf that is within the app directory.

Answer (score 0):

Your first problem is that your PDFs are not part of your app. You cannot invent random locations inside your project and expect the build tools to package that inside your APK.

The most likely way to ship PDFs with an app is to put them in an appropriately-located `assets/` directory. In a typical Android Studio project, that would be `app/src/main/assets/` off of the project root.

However, you have no direct way of giving other apps access to those assets. Your primary options are:

1. Copy the PDFs to files on the filesystem on [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/07/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) (e.g., `getFilesDir()`), then use `FileProvider` to make them available to other apps
2. Use [my `StreamProvider`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider), which can serve assets directly

> Or should I be using the file path of where it would be stored on the mobile device?

Neither assets nor anything else that you would use to ship PDFs in your APK are files on the filesystem of the device. They are kept inside the APK. You can use classes in the Android SDK (e.g., `AssetManager`) to get `InputStreams`, and you can use those to make copies of the content as files on the filesystem, if you so choose.

Comment: Thank you so much. I knew my understanding of how programs were kept on the system was flawed, but I didn't really know where to go from there. I'll play with it some more.